# Do pashupata-shaivists have mathas?

Tags: shaivism

I tried google search but I found nothing about mathas in pashupata shaivism. I am interested in becoming a ordained monk in hinduism sub-school pashupata shaivism. I would like to know where those mathas are located and if they have their own websites.

Comment: No, Pashupata Shaivism no longer exists as an organized sect.  But other Shaivite sects which evolved out of Pashupata Shaivism, like Shaiva Siddhanta, still exist.  Shaiva Siddhanta has Mathaks in Tamil Nadu, known wan Adheenams.

Comment: @riki You can contact Sri Divyesh brahmachari 096623 34664 he will guide you further.

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is the main place in Gujarat. Some people are in Karnataka also.

Kayavarohan is a village in the Vadodara district of the state of Gujarat, India. Kayavarohan is popularly known as Karvan and is situated on the National Highway 8 at a distance of 30 km from Vadodara. Kayavarohan is considered as the birthplace of Lakulisha

You can refer to [this](http://ktss.in/html/index.aspx?page=home) website for more details. From there the address is -

> SHREE KAYAVAROHANA SEVA SAMAJ
>   Kayavarohan-391 220,Dist.Vadodara
>   Gujarat-India.

Comment: Please provide & contact details to approach Mutts as well. :)

Comment: in website all is available. SHREE KAYAVAROHANA SEVA SAMAJ
Kayavarohan-391 220,Dist.Vadodara
Gujarat-India

Comment: @Rakesh Joshi Namah Shivay,
The website which u mentioned is not working, could u please tell how can i contact them?

Comment: @Rohit looks like website is no longer there but you can get most of information by searching lakulish temple kayavarohan.  There are videos too https://youtu.be/qyKlhDjlzRA