# Which scripture mentions about Kayarohana?

Tags: scripture, death

Kayarohana is a practice in Hinduism in which a person disappears instantly if (s)he wishes to die.

Which scripture mentions about kayarohana?

Comment: Could you add the source from where you came to know about this practice?

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto I listened from Telugu preaching.

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/18285/7853